# What are the differences between Xcode c++ and VS2010 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am quite new to C++, I have some java experience.

Currently I write a small c++ project using xcode. I just used the standard library. Then I create a project in VS2010. I “add existing items (My source file in xcode project) ” under source folder of the project. After that, I found the project could compile but it did not run properly in VS2010.

I heard that c++ code has portability, I don't understand why the code that run on xcode causes problem in VS2010.

In my source code, I write something like:

a.h:

```
  class a{
    public :
     int p ; 
    vector<Token*> v;
    a();
    int b();
    void c();
 }
```

a.cpp:

```
   a::a(){ //constructor of a
      p = 0;
      v.push_back(new Token("a",1));
   }
   int a::b(){
        ......
        //breakpoint to view p, v 
    c();
   }
   void a::c(){
        .......
       // when I set breakpoint here, in xcode, the debugger stops here.
       // in VS2010, it said the debugger did not hit this breakpoint.
   }
```

During runtime, xcode debugger shows vector and p properly, but inside VS2010 the debugger cannot show p and vector properly. If I expand the view of vector, the size of vector become very large in VS2010, but the vector size in xcode is correct.

Is there any way to import Xcode C++ project to VS2010? Or any method to solve the above problem?

Comment: One runs on a Mac, the other on a Windows box. That's a pretty big difference right there.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know XCode, but in general C++ this code `vector v;` shouldn't be compiled. You must give a type to vector

Comment: Are you building a **debug** executable, or a **release** one?  Release optimizations can reorganize your code and decide that `a::c()` does not need to exist.

Comment: Is it possible the code in a::c does "nothing" and the debugger just skip it ? 
On VS2010, you could try calling AfxDebugBreak(); to be certain the debugger will be called (assuming you are doing MFC stuff).

Comment: @boris - That was a code formatting problem. Now fixed.

Comment: Show the creation of variable of type `a`

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I used debug mode, and it didn't give me enough clues about the error. After using debug mode, I found the problem.  xcode and vs2010 use different way for vector initialization. I want the each object created from Class A contains a vector. In VS2010, I have to write as : A(): vector(n){}; in Xcode, I can directly write A(){inside the method I push elements, the element will be globally accessible}. Also there are other slightly differences. (i.e. declare variables). xcode x.h file: int p = 0; vs: should declare and initialize it separately.

Comment: @user1681877: `A() : v(n){}` is not necessary unless you're "adding" elements like `v[i] = ...;`.  `push_back` works just fine without a specified length for the vector; it's whole purpose is to add an element, resizing the storage space if needed (whereas `v[i] = ...;` is for assigning to already-existing elements), and one of two valid ways i can think of to make `v[i]` dynamically exist when `i >= v.size()` (the other way being `v.resize(i+1);`).

Comment: @cHao: I access `v[i]` outside the constructor, because I think I already pushed the elements in the vector in the constructor `a::a()`.  In my original code, the elements pushed back into vector are accessed in other method (`v[i]= sth` inside b()).  In vs, it had problem ; in Xcode, it just changed the element i which I pushed in the constructor.

Comment: @user1681877: VS has a couple of issues, but this probably isn't its fault.  Vectors are one of the most used classes in the standard library, with huge numbers of people "testing" VS's implementation of them every day.  If this were a VS issue, it would be a freaking huge one -- one so detrimental to the product that it would be fixed instantly if it ever even survived to production.  It's far more likely that til now, you've been getting away with using vectors in a non-standard, almost definitely UB-invoking way.

Comment: One way to verify if you're shooting yourself in the foot: `v.at(i)` does bounds checking, whereas `v[i]` doesn't.  If you were to use it instead, i'm about 97.4% certain you'd get exceptions in both VS and Xcode.

Comment: Linking libraries in Microsoft Visual Studio for C++ is a lot easier than linking libraries in Xcode. In Xcode one has to open a WorkSpace in order to merge libraries. In Microsoft Visual Studio for C++ one can just link any library that has previously been compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard defines an "abstract machine" that produces certain behaviors when presented with a well-formed C++ program.  Compilers are not required to reproduce all the behavior of the abstract machine, only its "observable behavior".

C++11 standard, §1.9/8:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into ﬁles shall be identical to one of the possible results that
>   execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-deﬁned.
>
> These collectively are referred to as the *observable behavior* of the program. [*Note*: More stringent correspondences between abstract and actual semantics may be deﬁned by each implementation. — *end note* ]

Note, "my functions will always be called at runtime" is not one of those requirements.  Compilers are allowed (indeed, encouraged) to optimize very aggressively, as long as the observable behavior matches that allowed by the standard.  The compiler is allowed to assume that you wrote a well-formed C++ program that does not cause undefined behavior.  Assuming it does so, if it notices that a function will have no *observable behavior* and will return a consistent value, it is allowed to omit the call altogether, compute the value at compile time, etc.

Whether VS's output is broken depends heavily on

- whether optimizations are disabled (many are on by default, but most compilers — including VC++ — will disable the non-essential ones if asked);
- whether `a::c()` is ever actually called outside of a debugger (if it's never used, the compiler might not even include it in the binary);
- whether it causes any observable side effects;
- in some cases, the contents of `a::b()`, and even of the caller;
- whether the program's behavior is undefined at any point prior to the would-be call to `a::b()` or `a::c()` — in particular, whether you're calling `a::b()` through a dangling or improperly-casted pointer or reference, etc (once the program runs off the rails, all bets are off);

and a bunch of other things.

I will say, though:  if VS lets you view the contents of `v` and `p`, and they have garbage values, then the problem is more likely the code than the debugger or compiler.  It could as easily say "i can't display this" (as it loves to do with .net objects :P ) if it didn't know how.  The fact that it thought it could, tried, and was wrong, is rather telling.